# Can I get full address from user on my site PHP?

Tags: php, google-maps

Now I'm using this code for getting the address:

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$long&sensor=false";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$address = json_decode($curlData);
```

There is result (Simplified. You guys can see full result here: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=10.8142,106.6438&sensor=false`):

```
 {
       "results" : [
          {
             "address_components" : [
                {
                   "long_name" : "C 2",
                   "short_name" : "C 2",
                   "types" : [ "route" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Tân Bình",
                   "short_name" : "Tân Bình",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Hồ Chí Minh",
                   "short_name" : "Hồ Chí Minh",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Việt Nam",
                   "short_name" : "VN",
                   "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                }
             ],
             "formatted_address" : "C 2, Tân Bình, Hồ Chí Minh, Việt Nam"
...
       "status" : "OK"
    }
```

It missing street name now. I want to get more information, like street name, house number ... How can I get full address of user?

Thank guys!

Comment: I don't think this API will be able to accurately return a house number for a given lat/lng pair. I just tried this for my address in England with the exact lat/lng of the house and it returned a range of house numbers rather than the actual number

Comment: @Mit Try `&result_type=street_address`. For a reference see [ReverseGeocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding)

Answer (score 0):

You are still getting the full address , its just that google does not give street address of all the places that you search for. An example

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=false

and

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=28.5355,77.3910&sensor=false

see both the examples.